# AspNet Identity UserManager Find with Select (optimal sql query)

Tags: sql, performance, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I have wcf fulRest service with AspNet Identity. My android app use this web service to communicate with database - I use ssl to make connection secure (my app is a mini game so it doesn't contain so important data, I belive that ssl is enough protection in this case).

I have function LoginUser(string userName, string unHashedPassword), if user exsists it returns user's id. In all other functions this id is used if action need information of curUser - for example I have function addComment(string userId, string msg) (this kind of methods still use ssl to protection of unwanted handle userId).

In LoginUser I get id (and a little more information like e-mail, gameLogin) by use:

```
using (var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(_context)))
{
            ApplicationUser user = userManager.Find(userName, password);
            if (user != null)
            {
                result = new LogInBaseData()
                {
                    Id = user.Id,
                    Email = user.Email,
                    Login = user.ApplicationLogin
                };
            }
}
```

But function Find generate huge query with select many unneeded data for me. Is any way to optimalizace it? I prefer do it by context.User.Where().Select() but I can't hash user's password.

Comment: Is this is a bottleneck? Does this cause a performance issue? Have you done the profiling? How many users do you have?

Comment: No it isn't a bottleneck. I haven't finished my app yet, so in practise I don't have any users at this moment but I want to implement everything how the best I can. In first version I don't plain use profiles. So if I good understand I shouldn't (generally?) think about that details if it isn't necessary (bottleneck or sth like that)?

Comment: In that case I would not worry about complex SQL request and trying to optimising it. Premature optimization is the root of all evil: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization

Comment: Ok thanks I will have it in mind, sth like my mum always says: not too much salt son :)